# Saving RPMs installed by dnf

Tags: rhel, rpm, dnf

I've got a question about yum. When I upgrade my system using dnf, it
downloads packages from the Web. Can I set dnf configuration so that I
could save rpm files for later use, with the same system but without Web
connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the option that you are looking for is `keepcache=1` which you would need to set in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`. After doing that you should see the files in `/var/cache/dnf/`.

If you would like to remove the downloaded `rpm`'s at a later time you can use `dnf clean packages`.

Comment: thank you @LucasMcCoy .  I have one more **Q** please, I think that this is going to work the _next time_ I `upgrade/download` a `RPM`, am I right? (if _yes_ , can you show me how to save the current RPMs.)

Comment: @010010001 Yes this will work for rpm's that you install going forward. Packages that you have already installed were deleted after they were installed. You can download the rpm from a website or you could reinstall the package via `dnf` to get a copy of the rpm.

Comment: great. thanks bro, that is going to help me a lot